# Get label value from dynamically created menu items [tkinter]

Tags: python, menu, tkinter

I have a cascade menu in a parent menu. The cascade items are created dynamically with `add_checkbutton` method.

A user should be able to "check" menu items and select/confirm them. However, I don't know how to access text in the menu items, to decide which item is selected.

Obvious solution is to generate `tk.StringVar` dynamically, but I would like to avoid that since it complicates the code significantly.

How to get value of the menu label/text in tkinter?  Is there other solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [entrycget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.entrycget-method) method of a menu item to get any of its attributes, including the label and value.

Comment: I don't understand with `entrycget` how one can get which item was selected. Would you mind elaborating a bit more please?

Comment: @Anthony: I don't quite understand your question. If you have a menu with checkboxes, several of them could be checked. You can iterate over them and use `entrycget` to get the value.

Comment: I intend to use them as buttons too, hence the need to identify which checkbutton is selected. My current solution is to store checkbutton labels and corresponding IntVar in a dictionary and pass label to the callback function.